# Aggregate status code from sub-scripts in a script

Tags: bash, exit-status

I have a bash script like this

```
#!/bin/bash

do-this parm someotherparam
do-something-else $varz $(commands)
and-also-do-this -something
finally-do-something-different -yes
```

I want this script to return exit status of 0, if all the individual commands above returned 0. I want it to return non-zero if any of the individual commands returned non-zero. I do not care what non-zero value is as long as it is, well, not 0.

Obviously, if we check status after each line, we can achieve our objective easily if only verbose. Since I'm new to bash, I was wondering if there is an idiomatic way of writing this.

*Note: I want all the commands to run regardless of their exit status, otherwise something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5195826/284111) would work*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

err=0

do-this parm someotherparam             ; (( err |= $? ))
do-something-else $varz $(commands)     ; (( err |= $? ))
and-also-do-this -something             ; (( err |= $? ))
finally-do-something-different -yes     ; (( err |= $? ))
```

This will initialize the variable `err` to zero and then, after each command, set `err` to `$err | $?` (a bitwise OR). This will set `err` to a non-zero number if any of the commands exit with a non-zero exit status, and it will remain non-zero to the end of the script.

You may `exit "$err"` at the end of the script if you wish.

A less manual way of getting the same result:

```
err=0
trap '(( err |= $? ))' ERR

# (rest of original script)
```

This sets an error trap that will set `err` in the same manner as above whenever a command exits with non-zero exit status. The trap will be executed under the same circumstances under which the `errexit` shell option (`set -e`) would have terminated the script. For simplicity, you may have the trap just set `err=1` if you want.

To unset the trap after a section of code, use

```
trap - ERR
```